# Get rectangle size inside a border

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

after various search, I'm yet facing the problem to get the rectangle inside a Border.
I have a custom component that extends a JPanel.
Within the constructor I add a Border with the createTitledBorder

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("My Title"),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2)));
```

Now, inside the paintComponent if I call getBound I obtain the rectangle of the Panel not the rectangle inside the border.
There is a way to get the inner rectangle size?

Comment: Maybe `getInsets()`?

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seem correct solution. getBounds() returns (0, 145, 317, 145) and getInsets returns (20,7,7,7). Why? I'm wrong?

Comment: You need to adjust the bounds by the insets. Alternatively, add the border to the enclosing component.

Comment: Add/subtract the insets from the bounds (+top/left -bottom/right)

Comment: Also check out the [SwingUtilities.calculateInnerArea(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#calculateInnerArea-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.Rectangle-)